# martingale and expectation

Tags: probability

The following is an old exam problem:

Let $\{X_n\}$, $n\geq0$, be a process adapted to a filtration $F_n$. Prove that $(X_n,F_n)$ is a martingale, if and only if for all bounded $F_n$-stopping time $\tau$, $EX_{\tau}=EX_0$ holds.

I know if $X_n$ is a martingale, then $X_{\tau}$ is a martingale by optional stopping theorem. Hence $E(X_{\tau})=E(E(X_{\tau}|F_{0}))=E(X_0)$. However I have trouble connecting the expectation to the conditional expectation for the other direction. It seems like it needs some smart way to define $\tau$ while I haven't thought of one. Thanks for any help.

Comment: The question is unclear. What precisely are you trying to prove?

Comment: Sorry for that. I changed it a little bit. Hope it's clear now..

Comment: Can you argue somehow that any fixed time (e.g. $\tau=n$) is a bounded stopping time, therefore $E(X_n)=E(X_0)$ for any $n$, thus $X$ is a martingale.

Comment: I get that $E(X_n)=E(X_0)$ for all n, but does that mean $X$ is a martingale? Shouldn't we prove $E(X_n|F_{n-1})=X_{n-1}$?

Comment: I believe you cannot go from $E[X_n] = E[X_0]$ to the martingale property. A counterexample: Let $X_n = aX_{n-1}+\epsilon_n$ where $\{ \epsilon_n\}$ is a sequence of iid rv's with mean 0. Then, if $|a|<1$, $E[X_n]=0=E[X_0]$ but $E[X_{n+1}\mid X_n] = aX_n$ (this is a so-called AR(1) process, btw )

Comment: any i.i.d. sequence e.g. standard normal distributions will be a counterexample as well

Comment: Yes, I was mistaken. Thanks for the counterexamples!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $A \in F_{n-1}$ and define $\tau =n-1$ on $A$,$\tau =n$ on $A^c$. Check that this is a stopping time.

Now

$$
E(X_{n-1} 1_A) +E(X_n 1_{A^c}) =E X_\tau= EX_0 = E X_n = E(X_n 1_A) + E(X_n 1_{A^c}),
$$
which shows what you want (why?).

Comment: Could you explain why $EX_0 = EX_n$?

Comment: @Barabara: If $\tau \equiv n$, this is a stopping time (why?). Thus, by assumption, we have $E X_n = E X_\tau = E X_0$.